# Why is my domain not working on other browsers?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dns, godaddy-api

I have created my domain name archents.app in Godaddy and I have redirected the namservers to google cloud DNS nameservers.

In cloud DNS I have created a A record pointing to my VM Instance.

But the website archents.app is only showing up on Android Brave Browser.

Why is this happening? How can I make archents.app work for all browsers?

Comment: If you just changed the name servers, it can take a few hours (up to 3 days) for the changes to propagate. Use an Internet tool such as https://mxtoolbox.com/ to check your DNS settings and verify there are as you require.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to recreate your use case and had one of my VM's assign a static public IP.

When I checked your domain `dig` command was providing correct IP, which meant you had A record set up OK.

```
$ dig archents.app

; <<>> DiG 9.11.5-P4-5.1+build1-Debian <<>> archents.app
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 24202
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 4096
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;archents.app.          IN  A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
archents.app.       299 IN  A   35.237.246.77

;; Query time: 41 msec
;; SERVER: 127.0.0.1#53(127.0.0.1)
;; WHEN: Tue Jan 07 10:03:46 CET 2020
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 57
```

So - to be sure everything works (in my case) I followed those steps:

1. [reserved external regional static address](https://console.cloud.google.com/networking/addresses) and attached it to my test VM
2. [created a public zone](https://console.cloud.google.com/net-services/dns) in cloud DNS (in your case put `archents.app` in the "DNS name" field.
3. added a record set to my zone (just selected A Record Type, set TTL to 1 minute (for convinience) and put my IP in the "IPv4 Address".

Please have a look into an official documentation [how to update a DNS record sets](https://cloud.google.com/dns/records/).

After a few minutes everything started working as expected.